# elasticsearch exception inserted for time type format

Tags: elasticsearch

es version: 7.10.1
kibana version: 7.10.0

**First, let me show my index mapping**

```
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 10000,
    "refresh_interval": "120s"
},
"mappings": {
    "date_detection": false,
    "dynamic_templates": [{
            "integers": {
                "match_mapping_type": "long",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "strings": {
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "user": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_dept_name": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_dept_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_leave_dept_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        },
        "user_dept_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        },
        "user_dimission_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        },
        "user_dimiss_apply_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        },
        "user_status": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "nested_object": {
            "type": "nested"
        },
        "operation_type": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "throw_exception": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        },
        "time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        }
    }
}
```

**in kibana, when I try to insert data, sometimes it can be inserted successfully, sometimes it prompts an exception.**

[exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZrl5.png)

[Succeeded this time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjuMi.png)

***I don’t know what the problem is, I hope friends will help me***

email: lcxkaka@foxmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `date` format for `time` field you are using `"format": "HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` (note `SSS`), but while indexing the data (`"10:12:08.61+0800"`) you are only having 2 digits of `S`.

So either you need to reformat your data as `"10:12:08.061+0800"`, or change the index mapping as shown below -

You need to change your mapping to -

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "HH:mm:ss.SSZ"     // note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks！But I still want to know why sometimes it can be inserted successfully in kibana

Comment: @chenxi13 can you share any sample index data, when it is inserted successfully. It will be inserted in those cases when `time` is in the format `HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: the mapping: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORIVg.png
the data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC7jR.png

Comment: @chenxi13 with your current mapping, if you try to insert the document having `"time":"10:12:08.61+0800"`, then you will get *date_time_parse_exception*. This is because the format of the date does not match the format given in the index mapping.

Comment: my index mapping `"time": "HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`, but now when insert 

    POST admin_group_finance-202101/_doc
    {
     "time": "10:12:08.61+0800"
    }

sometimes successful, sometimes get exception

Comment: i think insert `"time":"10:12:08.61+0800" `when mapping is `HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` alaways should be excepiton, but sometimes it be succeeds